# Sitecore media ashx not resizing the image (version 7.2)

Tags: best-practices, presentation, media-library

We have 3 (near identical) Sitecore sites on a development server and 2 out of the 3 fail to resize the images using the inbuilt Sitecore query string parameters.

**Example URL:** `/~/media/59274CA8941B4540B7B1A6C0FEAE9F84.ashx?w=300&h=30`

The media image is returned but it fails to resize the image.

So far I've tried file permissions, `config diff (web.config and showconfig.aspx)` but nothing obvious stands out.

I'm thinking its something in IIS but cannot think what.

Comment: Try removing `\App_Data\MediaCache` folder and resetting IIS

Answer (score 16):

As of Sitecore 7.5+ (applies to the latest 7.2 versions as well), Sitecore introduced a media request protection for image resizing (to make sure an attacker can't overload your server with image resize requests)

In this case you have two options:

1. Add a media hash to the resizing requests, like that:

```cs
    Sitecore.Resources.Media.HashingUtils.ProtectAssetUrl (
                           Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(
                               myMediaItem,
                               new MediaUrlOptions()
                               {
                                   Language = Context.Language,
                                   Width = 100,
                                   Height = 75
                               }))
```

2. Disable media request protection (not recommended)

You can find more details in this blog post:
http://kirkegaard-at.blogspot.sg/2015/06/media-hash-and-resizing.html